# Database Storing long Text Strings

Tags: database, text, data-storage

What's the best method to store long text string (> 5000 chars)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database.  With SQL server, you can use varchar(MAX) or text.

http://www.teratrax.com/articles/varchar_max.html explains about different storage types.

and of course, good ol' dependable msdn...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: It's SQL Server 2005. Thanks.